# Change Text To Button With hidden and shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, anki

I have this code that I use in a app called *Anki*,
Which is a flashcard app that helps me remember new words.
I have this code that writes a text when I click on it shows the content of the hint field which that I added when adding the new card,

```
{{#Hint}}
    <div id="hint" class="hidden">
        <p class="trigger">[ click to show hint ]</p>
        <p class="payload">{{Hint}}</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var hint = document.getElementById('hint');
        hint.addEventListener('click', function() { this.setAttribute('class', 'shown'); });
    </script>
{{/Hint}}
```

All I want is write function of that text above to button with style like this code, for example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {background-color: #4CAF50;} /* Green */
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="button button1">Green</button>

</body>
</html>
```

And I want that when I press the button for the first time, it shows me the content of the hint field,
And when I press it for the second time, it hides it, and so on...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What part of this code is not working for you? Is the Javascript not working how you want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly you wanna add and remove some certain css class on each sequential click?

In that case, toggling class will do the thing:

```
hint.addEventListener('click', function() {  hint.classList.toggle("shown"); });
```

And css can be for example something like:

```
#hint .payload {display: none};

#hint.shown .payload {display: block}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
But when i replace this line
```
        hint.addEventListener('click', function() { this.setAttribute('class', 'shown'); });`
```
with this line which you posted toggle doesn't work and It does not show the content of the hint field for some reason

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vm4hpjg0/ Here is an example with your html. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but how can I add buttons instead of the normal shape,
Like this page
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve. Do you want just a "modern" style for a button? Should that button in the place where "[ click to show hint ]" is now or what?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want a modern button instead of [ click to show hint ] for examply like button in this page https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: Is this something that you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljy7khoq/ . 
You have to learn CSS in order to make a modern look design, there are also a various libs like bootstrap and similar that are usefull...

Comment: I get it, Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

With your contribution of style and general idea, it is to add a small part of js to your script.

In relation to what was said by @munleashed, it could also be used by `onclick` event.

```js
var hint = document.getElementById('hint');

function hide() {
  hint.classList.toggle('shown');
}
```

```css
.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button1 {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
#hint .payload {
  display: none;
}
#hint.shown .payload {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hint" class="hidden">
  <button class="button button1" onclick="hide()">[ TOUCH ]</button>
  <p class="payload">SOME HINT HERE</p>
</div>
<!-- 
<button class="button button1" onclick="hide()">[ TOUCH ]</button>

<div id="hint" class="hidden">
    <p class="payload">SOME HINT HERE</p>
</div> 
-->
```